# c pointers and memory - understanding

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

the code is working it cut the first word and put it, in the end, the text. I don't understand one line in the code, let say my string is "hello world".

when I use the code "*p++ = '\0';"

before this line:  `p: "world"`

```
               s: "hello world"
```

after this line:  `p: "world"`

```
              s: "hello"
```

why did it change? and cut the word world?

the full code:

```
void func(char *s)
{
    char * p = strchr(s, ' ');
    char * t = (char*)malloc(strlen(s) + 1);

    if (!t)
    {
        printf("Memory allocated failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    *p++ = '\0';
    strcat(strcat(strcpy(t, p), " "), s);
    strcpy(s, t);
    free(t);
 }
```

Comment: You really need to be accurate here! Otherwise there is no way to understand what you see. Before should be `p: " world"` (with leading whitespace!)

Comment: Your code is incomplete; in particular, it seems to be missing a `main()` function and at least one `#include`. Please [edit] your code so it's a [mcve] of your problem, then we can try to reproduce and solve it. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).

Comment: If `s` have not any space execution of `*p++` cause seg fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the assignment to `*p`, you have the following:

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
s: |'H'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'|' '|'W'|'o'|'r'|'l'|'d'| 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                         ^
   +---+                 |          
p: |   | ----------------+
   +---+
```

After executing `*p++ = '\0';`, you have

```
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
s: |'H'|'e'|'l'|'l'|'o'| 0 |'W'|'o'|'r'|'l'|'d'| 0 |
   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                             ^
   +---+                     |          
p: |   | --------------------+
   +---+
```

IOW, you've replaced the blank space in `s` with a *string terminator*, which is why you only see `"Hello"` when you print `s`.

Comment: Care to add the zero terminator after `world`?

Comment: @grek40: Done.  Woke up a couple of hours earlier than usual, brain isn't quite in gear yet.

Comment: This works for only a string s similar to hello world that have a space in it.

Comment: @EsmaeelE yes, surprisingly, an explanation for the program behavior with specified example data works for those data and not for something completely different. It doesn't really add value to raise questions about hypothetical missing characters unless the question gives specific reasons why bad values are to be expected. Imagine someone commenting *"what if `i` is `MAX_INT`"* everytime you write `i++` in an answer.

Comment: @EsmaeelE: The OP was asking why *one particular program* was producing *one particular output*, which is what I addressed.  If you think I missed something important, you're free to provide your own answer.

Comment: @JohnBode for that particular case your answer is good, but not enough. I only want to express using '*p++' without any checking may be cause problems.